Build errors when using premake/ninja on Windows with a C++ Walnut/Vulkan project
I'm trying to build this starter template for a C++ GUI application: https://github.com/StudioCherno/WalnutAppTemplate.
The batch script scripts/Setup.bat calls a premake5 executable with the vs2022 option, and that works fine. However, I'd like to use CLI tools to build, so I'm trying to use Ninja with clang. I've added the Ninja module for premake, so now I can do premake5 ninja in the project root, which seems to create the files as it should.
But when I try to build with ninja, I get many errors, most (if not all) of which seem to be related to Ninja not being able to find the libraries it needs.
Here's the output:
❯ ninja
[14/36] cxx Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/ImGuiBuild.o
FAILED: Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/ImGuiBuild.o
clang++ -MD -MP -m64 -O2 -std=c++17 -DWL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS -DWL_DIST -Isrc -I../vendor/imgui -I../vendor/glfw/include -I../vendor/stb_image -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.3.283.0/Include -I../vendor/glm -x c++ -MF Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/ImGuiBuild.o.d -c -o Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/ImGuiBuild.o Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/ImGui/ImGuiBuild.cpp
Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/ImGui/ImGuiBuild.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'backends/imgui_impl_vulkan.cpp' file not found
    1 | #include "backends/imgui_impl_vulkan.cpp"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[21/36] cc Walnut/vendor/glfw/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/GLFW/win32_window.o
FAILED: Walnut/vendor/glfw/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/GLFW/win32_window.o
clang -MD -MP -m64 -O2 -D_GLFW_WIN32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -x c -MF Walnut/vendor/glfw/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/GLFW/win32_window.o.d -c -o Walnut/vendor/glfw/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/GLFW/win32_window.o Walnut/vendor/glfw/src/win32_window.c
Walnut/vendor/glfw/src/win32_window.c:555:115: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'void *' to parameter of type 'DWORD' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wint-conversion]
  555 |                     AdjustWindowRectEx(&border_thickness, GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_CAPTION, FALSE, NULL);
      |                                                                                                                   ^~~~
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\18\include\__stddef_null.h:26:14: note: expanded from macro 'NULL'
   26 | #define NULL ((void*)0)
      |              ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22621.0\um\winuser.h:9023:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'dwExStyle' here
 9023 |     _In_ DWORD dwExStyle);
      |                ^
Walnut/vendor/glfw/src/win32_window.c:565:17: error: call to undeclared function 'DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  565 |                 DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
      |                 ^
Walnut/vendor/glfw/src/win32_window.c:578:22: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
  578 |                 auto hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
      |                 ~~~~ ^
      |                 int
Walnut/vendor/glfw/src/win32_window.c:578:27: error: call to undeclared function 'DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  578 |                 auto hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
      |                           ^
Walnut/vendor/glfw/src/win32_window.c:1276:18: error: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit int [-Wimplicit-int]
 1276 |             auto hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
      |             ~~~~ ^
      |             int
Walnut/vendor/glfw/src/win32_window.c:1276:23: error: call to undeclared function 'DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea'; ISO C99 and later
do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1276 |             auto hr = DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hWnd, &margins);
      |                       ^
6 errors generated.
[23/36] cxx Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Image.o
FAILED: Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Image.o
clang++ -MD -MP -m64 -O2 -std=c++17 -DWL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS -DWL_DIST -Isrc -I../vendor/imgui -I../vendor/glfw/include -I../vendor/stb_image -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.3.283.0/Include -I../vendor/glm -x c++ -MF Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Image.o.d -c -o Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Image.o Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Image.cpp
Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Image.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'imgui.h' file not found
    3 | #include "imgui.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[25/36] cxx Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Input.o
FAILED: Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Input.o
clang++ -MD -MP -m64 -O2 -std=c++17 -DWL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS -DWL_DIST -Isrc -I../vendor/imgui -I../vendor/glfw/include -I../vendor/stb_image -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.3.283.0/Include -I../vendor/glm -x c++ -MF Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Input.o.d -c -o Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Input.o Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Input/Input.cpp
In file included from Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Input/Input.cpp:1:
Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Input\Input.h:5:10: fatal error: 'glm/glm.hpp' file not found
    5 | #include <glm/glm.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[26/36] cxx Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Random.o
FAILED: Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Random.o
clang++ -MD -MP -m64 -O2 -std=c++17 -DWL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS -DWL_DIST -Isrc -I../vendor/imgui -I../vendor/glfw/include -I../vendor/stb_image -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.3.283.0/Include -I../vendor/glm -x c++ -MF Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Random.o.d -c -o Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Random.o Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Random.cpp
In file included from Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Random.cpp:1:
Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut\Random.h:5:10: fatal error: 'glm/glm.hpp' file not found
    5 | #include <glm/glm.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[27/36] cxx Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Application.o
FAILED: Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Application.o
clang++ -MD -MP -m64 -O2 -std=c++17 -DWL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS -DWL_DIST -Isrc -I../vendor/imgui -I../vendor/glfw/include -I../vendor/stb_image -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.3.283.0/Include -I../vendor/glm -x c++ -MF Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Application.o.d -c -o Walnut/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/Walnut/Application.o Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Application.cpp
In file included from Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut/Application.cpp:1:
Walnut/Walnut/src/Walnut\Application.h:10:10: fatal error: 'imgui.h' file not found
   10 | #include "imgui.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
[31/36] cxx Walnut/vendor/imgui/bin-int/Dist-windows-x86_64/ImGui/imgui.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

How can I fix these errors?
I'm using premake5 5.0.0-beta2, ninja 1.12.1, clang 18.1.6, on Windows 11. And I've installed the Vulkan API version 1.3.283.0.

Have you installed the missing libraries ImGui and OpenGL Mathematics?

They are included in Walnut/vendor/GLFW, Walnut/vendor/glm, Walnut/vendor/imgui.

For non-include errors, you compile .c files as C and not as C++ compileas might fix that or change file extension.

For include path, where is "backends/imgui_impl_vulkan.cpp"? Is -Isrc -I../vendor/imgui -I../vendor/glfw/include -I../vendor/stb_image -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.3.283.0/Include -I../vendor/glm correct in that regard?
